# Erro ao retornar dados de banco mysql

Tags: php, sql, select, imagem

Eu fiz um formulário normal que retorna os dados no HTML. Então resolvi inserir imagens no banco de dados e ai deu um aviso:

> "Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   E:\sites\htdocs\progdesenv2\admin\acao.php on line 14"

Até onde eu entendi, está dizendo que é uma array de conversão para texto certo? Então, fiquei com algumas dúvidas:
**1** - Como eu faço para usar texto e imagem juntas??
**2** - Quando eu insiro os dados no formulário ele só traz no HTML do ultimo registro que eu inseri mas eu queria que trouxesse todos os dados do banco(tipo uma tabela).
**3** - No meu ultimo post disseram pra eu usar msqli ao invés de msql mas eu tentei usar e deu muitos erros por isso eu tirei, tem algum modo certo de se usar ou é só colocar o "i" na frente do msql?
**4** - Eu pesquisei na internet e coloquei no campo da imagem que ele é tipo LONGBLOB é a melhor alternativa?

**TRÁS OS DADOS DO BANCO**

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";
$busca = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM formulario  ORDER BY nome ASC");
if (mysql_num_rows($busca))
{

    while ($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($busca))
    {
        extract($resultado);
        $l1 = $nome;
        $l2 = $idade;
        $l3 = $editor1;
        $l4 = $imagem;
    }       
}

?>
```

**INSERE OS DADOS NO BANCO**

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";
if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'enviado'){

        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $idade = $_POST['idade'];
        $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
        $editor1 = $_POST['editor1'];
        $imagem = $_FILES['imagem'];

        if(empty($nome) || empty($idade) || empty($telefone) || empty($editor1) || empty($imagem)){
                echo "Preencha os campos corretamente";
            }else{
                $insereDados = mysql_query("INSERT INTO formulario (nome, idade, telefone, editor1, imagem) VALUES ('$nome', '$idade', '$telefone', '$editor1', '$imagem' )");  
                echo "Enviado com sucesso!!";
            }
    }
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="formulario">
  <form action="acao.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome:"><br>
    <input type="text" name="idade" placeholder="Idade:"><br>
    <input type="text" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone:"><br>
    <input name="imagem" type="file"/><BR>
    <div class="tarea"><textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Mensagem:" ></textarea></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="enviado">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar Informações">
  </form>
</section>
```

> Atualizei o código abaixo e agora não dá nenhum erro só que no lugar da imagem ele trás escrito array o que pode ser?:

```
<div>
<hgroup><h2>NOME</h2><h2>IDADE</h2><h2>MENSAGEM</h2><h2>IMAGEM</h2></hgroup>
    <?php
    include "conexao.php";
    $busca = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM formulario  ORDER BY nome ASC");
    while ($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($busca)){

     echo '<div>'.$resultado['nome'].'</div>';
     echo '<div>'.$resultado['idade'].'</div>';
     echo '<div>'.$resultado['editor1'].'</div>';
     echo '<div>'?><img src ="imagem/<?php echo $resultado['imagem']?> <?php echo '</div>';
} ?>
</div>
```

Comment: da um print_r ou var_dump em $imagem pra ver o tipo da variável

Comment: Outra coisa que pelo seu script esta salvando um array do $_FILE e não o conteúdo da imagem

Comment: A linha 14 é qual?

Comment: @rray a linha 14 é esta $insereDados = mysql_query("INSERT INTO formulario (nome, idade, telefone, editor1, imagem) VALUES ('$nome', '$idade', '$telefone', '$editor1', '$imagem' )");

Comment: Essa resposta pode te ajudar [como utilizar o `mysqli` da forma certa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221548/erro-no-insert-msqli/221563#221563)

Answer (score 1):

Depois de inserir o registro, faça a consulta e exiba todos os resultados com as formatações dentro do while e não fora.

Você escreveu os valores após o while isso significa que apenas o último resultado será exibido, o uso do [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) não parece necessario. Faça dessa forma para obter o resultado desejado

```
<?php while ($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($busca)){ ?>
<div>
    <hgroup><h2>NOME</h2><h2>IDADE</h2><h2>MENSAGEM</h2><h2>IMAGEM</h2></hgroup>
    <div><?php echo $resultado['nome'];?></div>    
    <div><?php echo $resultado['idade'];?></div>
    <div><?php echo $resultado['editor1'];?></div>
    <div><?php echo $resultado['imagem'];?></div>
</div> <br>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: eu fiz isto que disse apareceu um warning e um notice:

Notice: Undefined variable: busca in E:\sites\htdocs\progdesenv2\admin\index.php on line 35

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in E:\sites\htdocs\progdesenv2\admin\index.php on line 35

linha 35: <?php while ($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($busca)){ ?>

Comment: @EstenioRibeiroNobrega os códigos da pergunta estão em um arquivo so?

Comment: não estão separados, o unico código que está junto com o HTML é o que trás os dados do banco

Comment: como está no post editado acima eu consegui trazer o texto mas ainda está dando problema para fazer o upload da imagem, alguma ideia do que seja?

Comment: Vou editar a resposta quando chegar em casa.

Comment: eu atualizei o código e como eu disse acima ele não dá erro mas aparece escrito array no lugar da imagem, tipo será que eu não tenho que fazer o echo dentro de uma tag img???