# Erro no insert MSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Estou mudando de mysql_ para mysqli, tudo funciona(update e delete) mais no insert não salva.... onde está o erro?

arquivo do insert:

```
include("config/con_mysqli.php");


$sigla                  = $_REQUEST['sigla'];
$nome                   = $_REQUEST['nome'];    


mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

$sql = "insert into setores(sigla,nome) values('$sigla','$nome')";



@mysqli_query($con,$sql);



echo json_encode(array(
    'idsetor' => mysqli_insert_id($con),
    'sigla' => $sigla,
    'nome' => $nome
));
```

Comment: Veja se assim parece algum erro assim: `mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));`. Não use `@` pois ela oculta o erro aí vc não vê a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Estou usando datagrid easyui, então mesmo que tenha erro não aparece....

Comment: Acessa esse arquivo php direto, pode colocar os valores fixos para `$sigla` e `$nome` apenas para teste.

Comment: {"idsetor":48,"sigla":null,"nome":null} retornou isso.... direto salva.

Comment: vc não esqueceu de colocar o `$_POST['nome']` algo assim? pelo menos não tem esse código na pergunta.

Comment: não.... ele funcioan perfeitamente com mysql_ mas tem algum problema no mysqli

Comment: editei lá... havia esquecido de mostrar essa parte.....

Comment: funcionou era alguma coisa com o mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente vamos aos conceitos.
Você está saindo do modo procedural do `mysqli_query` para o orientado a objetos. Comentei esse caso a pouco tempo nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220978/banco-de-dados-n%C3%A3o-funciona/220997#220997).

O problema é que você ainda está bagunçando a forma procedural com a orientada a objetos na hora de trabalhar com `mysqli_query`.

Como seria o correto trabalhar com o `mysqli_query orientado a objetos:

**Conexão** (Não que a sua esteja errado)

```
// Conecta ao banco de dados
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');
```

**Valiando a conexão**

```
// Verifica se ocorreu algum erro
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('Não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados: ' . 
         mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

**Procure usar o [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Facilita sua vida**

```
/* Prepared statement, Primeiro parte prepare o sql.
Verifique se não ocorreu erro */
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)"))) {
    echo "Falha no Prepare: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

// Segunda parte passe os parâmetros e execute a query
$id = 1;
if (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $id)) {
    echo "Falha no bind_param: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Falha ao executar a query: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Mais um [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747868/how-to-insert-into-mysql-using-prepared-statement-with-php). Outra coisa, evite usar o `@` nas consultas a banco ou em qualquer lugar do seu código. Omitir os erros e avisos apenas lhe prejudica a produzir um bom código.

Espero que te ajude.