# mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool

Tags: php

Estou com um erro na hora de autenticar no PHP 7. Esse meu código funciona no PHP 5. Fiz as mudanças de `msql` para `msqli`, mas o problema continua. Alguém pode dar uma força?

```
<?php

include "conexao.php";
$con = conectar();

$username = $_POST["username"];
$senha    = $_POST["senha"];



$resultado = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM usuario where username='$username'");
$linhas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado); // erro nesta linha

if ($linhas==0)     {


echo "<html><body>";
echo "<p align= \"center\"> Usuário não encontrado ! </p>";
echo "<p align= \"center\"> <a href = \"login.html\"> Voltar </a> </p>";
echo "</body></html>";

} else {

if ($senha != mysqli_result($resultado, 0, "senha")) {              

echo "<html><body>";
echo "<p align= \"center\"> A senha está incorreta ! </p>";
echo "<p align= \"center\"> <a href = \"login.html\"> Voltar </a> </p>";
echo "</body></html>";

} else          {        

header ("Location: pagina_inicial.php");

}

}               

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Essa resposta pode te ajudar [como utilizar o `mysqli` da forma certa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221548/erro-no-insert-msqli/221563#221563)

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que existe um erro na sua query. De acordo com a [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php), ao usar o mysqli_query:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Por isso que você está passando um boolean para `$resultado`. Tente alterar a sua query para: `"SELECT * FROM usuario where username=$username"`.

Comment: Eu alterei a query como você disse, mas ainda está dando erro.